# An example of a sequence $x=(x_n)\in \ell_p$ such that $x\not\in \ell p'$, for all $p'<p$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $1<p<+\infty$ . Give an example of a sequence $x=(x_n)\in \ell_p$ such that $x\not\in \ell_{p'}$, for all $p'<p$. There is a hint that I do not understand. Take the sequence $x_n=\dfrac{1}{n\ln^2 n},\ n=2,3,\dots$. Why does this sequence prove this exercise? Thanks

Comment: Using the integral test, one can see that the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n\log^2n}\in\ell_1$ for
$$\int^\infty_2\frac{1}{x\log^2x}\,dx=\int^\infty_{\log 2}\frac{du}{u^2}<\infty$$

On the other hand,
For $0<q<1$ fix $0<\varepsilon < 1-q$. Then 
$$n^q\log^{2q}(n)\leq n^{q+\varepsilon}$$
for $n$ large enough. Thus $\frac{1}{n^{q+\varepsilon}}<\frac{1}{n^q\log^{2q}(n)}$ for $n$ large enough. Can you finish from this?

Comment: I get it thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a sum $\sum a_n$ where $a_n$ are positive and monotonic, the sum is finite if and only if $\sum 2^n * a_{2^n}$ is finite. This is well known fact and its proof can be found in many places.
Applying this in your case for ${x_n}^{1/p}$ one gets $\sum ({x_n}^{1/p})^p$ is finite if and only if $\sum 2^n*(\frac{1}{2^n*n^2})$ is finite. The last sum is $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ so it is finite. However, $\sum ({x_n}^{1/p})^p{'}$ = $\sum {x_n}^{q}$
where $q < 1$ and using the rule on the top of the post again one gets that this is finite only if $\sum 2^n*(\frac{1}{2^n*n^2})^q$ is finite. But in the last sum the general term does not got to $0$ so the sum must be inifinite.